# Guice singleton created multiple times in one module

Tags: java, dependency-injection, guice

I am using Guice through Play in Java. My class is annotated as a `@Singleton`:

```
import com.google.inject.Singleton;

@Singleton
@Slf4j
public class HistoryService {
    @Inject
    public HistoryService(Configuration configuration) {
        log.error("I am being created");
    }
}
```

My module registers some bindings:

```
@Override
protected void configure() {
    super.configure();

    bind(Flows.class).toProvider(FlowConfigProducer.class);
    bind(FlowManager.class).asEagerSingleton();

    bind(ApplicationLifecycle.class).to(AppLifecycleHandler.class).asEagerSingleton();

    bindService(FileService.class, FileServiceImpl.class);
}
```

There are some dependencies that may be interesting:

- `FlowManager` injects `HistoryService` in its constructor
- `AppLifecycleHandler` injects `FlowManager` in its constructor (and so indirectly the `HistoryService`)

I am noticing that the `I am being created` is printed twice and according to the stack traces once when then `AppLifecycleHandler` is instantiated and once when the `FlowManager` is created (in that order, as `FlowManager` is a dependency of `AppLifecycleHandler`).

Now the first problem is already that `FlowManager` is created multiple times. It is bound as `eagerSingleton`. The same goes for my `HistoryService`. It shouldnt be created multiple times.

I have also tried registering the `HistoryService` in the module with `bind(HistoryService.class).in(Singleton.class)` or `bind(HistoryService.class).asEagerSingleton()` but to no avail. It always creates two instances of my service. What is causing this?

**EDIT**: Because I found a question mentioning that adding `in(Scopes.SINGLETON)` fixed their problem I have tried that as well, however this did not change anything and IntelliJ already noted that its redundant to specify that.

**EDIT2**:

Here are the constructors:

```
@Inject
FlowManager(ActorSystem actorSystem, HistoryService historyService, Configuration configuration) {
    this.materializer = ActorMaterializer.create(actorSystem);
    this.historyService = historyService;
    this.tempFolder = configuration.getString("application.temp-folder", Option.empty()).get();
}


@Inject
AppLifecycleHandler(FlowManager flowManager, Injector injector) {
    this.flowManager = flowManager;
    this.injector = injector;
}
```

The injectors were mentioned in the comments, however at least according to the documentation getting the guice injector of Play should be done with DI of the injector, so I think I am not creating multiple injectors.

Comment: Please show how you write the constructors of `FlowManager` and `AppLifecycleHandler`. Also, are you sure you're using only one injector ?

Comment: I have added the constructors. I am not entirely sure, because Play is wiring up Guice, I am injecting an Injector in the constructor of `AppLifecycleHandler`, however that should get me the one from Play and not a new one.

Comment: But 100 points to you :). Removing the injected `Injector` in the lifecycle handler fixes the problem. So it did create a second injector to inject into my instance :(

Comment: Injecting `com.google.inject.Injector` instead of `play.inject.Injector` does not cause the same problem.